# Linq query to set datasource field for radioButton

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a database with three tables as below

Tbl 1

> Product - ID, Name, Description, MediaType

Tbl 2

> Media - ID, MediaName, MediaDescription

Tbl3

> ProductAndMedia - ID, MediaID, ProductID

In **tbl3** MediaID and ProductID are **Foreign Keys**.

I then have a Linq query

```
Dim query = From MyDataContext.ProductAndMedia.Where(Function(i) i.ProductID = PiD).ToList()
```

It is then made as a DataSource for a radioButton

```
rbt.DataSource = query
rbt.DataTextField = ????
rbt.DataValueField = "ID"
rbt.DataBind()
```

What i am trying to achieve is to have the MediaName to be the TextField for the radionButton list. If i use MediaID, ProductID as the textfield then it shows the ID for that particular product/media but i am after the Name in this instance.

Is there anyway to get the name in this way or would i need to make another call to the database to get the name by ID?

Comment: rbt.DataTextField = the name of the field in the table you want to display.

Comment: Using MediaName produces an error that the field cannot be found

Comment: That is because `MediaName` does not belong to `MyDataContext.ProductAndMedia`, see what table your calling?

Comment: Thats correct however when i use Linq to SQL i usually can do something like ....ProductAndMediaSource.FirstOrDefault().Media.MediaName so i was wondering if there is an alternative to the way im using it above?

Comment: I don't think you can bind a List to the `DataSource` just one object - it's not a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the fields you are interested in as a new anonymous type (or create a class, or use `KeyValuePair`, etc.).

```
Dim query = From MyDataContext.ProductAndMedia _
    .Where(Function(i) i.ProductID = PiD) _
    .Select(Function(i) New With { .ID = i.ID, .MediaName = i.Media.MediaName }) _
    .ToList()
rbt.DataSource = query
rbt.DataTextField = "MediaName"
rbt.DataValueField = "ID"
rbt.DataBind()
```

**Update**

Looks like this is probably the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5721186/2278086).