# asp:DropDownList Linq-to-sql data source binding text field to relation-property value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu, webforms

So I am using Linq-to-sql to communicate with my sql server and i want to populate a asp.net dropdown list with data from my database. The problem is I want the text value that is visible to the user to bind to a relation-property.

I have a list of linq-to-sql objects and each of those objects has a one-to-many relation child and parent property. The parentproperty is simply called "parent" which is also a linq-to-sql object that contains a name property of type string. The problem is I want to bind DataTextField to the parent.name property.

The code below is from my code-behind file which does not work at the moment where DropDownList is my dropdownlist and Table.GetAll() returns a list of linq-to-sql objects:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Bind_Drop_Down();
    }
}
protected void Bind_Drop_Down()
{
    List<linq-to-sql-class-name> objects = Table.GetAll();
    if (objects != null)
    {
        DropDownList.DataSource = objects;
        DropDownList.DataTextField = "parent.name";
        DropDownList.DataValueField = "id";
        DropDownList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I think this can be solved by putting the raw query to my database right above this code and make it so that it creates a new object with new parameters but I do not want this. I want to keep the raw queries in my Table class which should only return proper linq-to-sql objects.

I get the following error message when executing the above code where linq-to-sql-class-name is a placeholder for the actual name:

```
DataBinding: 'linq-to-sql-class-name' does not contain a property with the name 'parent.name'
```

My question is: can this be done?

EDIT:

I added some code to verify the property actually exists, I tried printing the parent.name property of each object in the list and it actually printed it as expected.

```
protected void Bind_Drop_Down()
{
    List<linq-to-sql-class-name> objects = Table.GetAll();
    if (objects != null)
    {
        foreach(linq-to-sql-class-name oneObject in objects)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oneObject.parent.name);
        }
        DropDownList.DataSource = objects;
        DropDownList.DataTextField = "parent.name";
        DropDownList.DataValueField = "id";
        DropDownList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

It printed this in the debug console:

```
name1 lastname1
name2 lastname2
...etc
...etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse I found a suitable solution right after I posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721761/3266294